# Transaction does not get mined on rinkeby

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, solc, truffle-hdwallet-provider

so I'm trying to deploy my first contract on rinkeby using web3 and truffle/hdwallet-provider.

even with different gas prices it doesn't get mined.Please help out.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require('web3');
const {abi , bytecode} = require('./compile');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'december blossom school two brief lunar siren truth purse violin car submit',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/737d5964ada94e2a8d812f1414c89c4e'
)
const web3 = new Web3(provider)
async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

const deploy = async() =>{
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('attempting to deploy from account',accounts[0])
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
        .deploy({data:'0x' +bytecode ,arguments: ['hii']})
        .send({from: accounts[0],gas: 1500000,gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3)})
    console.log('contract deployed to', result.options.address);
}
deploy()
```

**Output** :

```
 node deploy.js
attempting to deploy from account 0x010Ff624891610c8538824AB6F5AF4abfD1c3bfd
Enter gas-price or leave empty to use 1000000000: 1050000000
Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
C:\Users\Ketan Verma\Desktop\blockchain\solidity-etherium\index\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { "use strict";var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in
Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var arguments_=[];var thisProgram="./this.program";var quit_=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof process.versions==="object"&&typeof process.versions.node==="string";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var scriptDirectory="";function locat

RuntimeError: abort(Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at process.abort (C:\Users\Ketan Verma\Desktop\blockchain\solidity-etherium\index\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:14506)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:119:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
```

Comment: There's a pending transaction from 2 minutes ago. Is that yours? Previous ones are from 11 days ago BTW, and your question here is from 1 hour ago, so I can't quite see where your transaction has gone to.

Comment: I was ill so didn't work a couple of dats, now tried it again,same result.I've tried everything i could think of

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9e97cd35a6175831b5f802ccef9d4045bea7c6bec2aa5c024d15ce22038b9fc2), you have used a gas-price of 0.00000000003 Ether (0.03 Gwei (30,000,000 wei)).

According to your question, you have used in your transaction a gas-price of 1,050,000,000 wei.

Conclusion: you are not telling the truth (though you are probably not doing it intentionally).

Comment: yes, i didn't know this, but how would i fix it.I'm still new to this so really confused